# Can I change the role of a particular key on mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard

Can I assign a functionality to a particular key in the keyboard , specifically I don't want enter to be used for renaming rather than opening a file or document , can I assign the functionality by my own ?

Comment: Yes you can. Use Karabiner (https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)

Comment: you mean in the Finder? And just in the Finder?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t get you , I meant if I want to change the functionality of “Enter” key , can I do it on my own ? I dont want to use it for renaming , I want to use it for entering a document / folder.